# Image not being displayed in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

I want to add a brand logo to my `_layout.cshtml` page in my ASP.NET MVC application. I added the necessary folder along with the `.jpg` file to the project. Inside my layout page, I added the necessary image tag along with the path for the file:

This is my `_Layout.cshtml`:

```
<img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/file.jpg")" alt="can't find the path" />
<img src="~/Content/file.jpg" alt="can't find the path" />
```

Here's what it renders out:

[image]

I've tried coding the image tag in two different ways, but the layout page doesn't display either image. Any thoughts on a solution?

Comment: What does the **rendered** HTML look like?

Comment: Added the picture to the question.

Comment: no, by "rendered HTML" we mean what does the HTML text sent to the browser look like - **not** how a graphical web-browser renders the page on your display. Use the "View source" feature of your browser (don't use the DOM Inspector as that won't show you the _raw_ HTML).

Comment: Opened the app in chrome. right clicked and pressed "view page source". this is what I got in return.                                                                                                           
 <img b-431wedhg7i src="/Content/file.jpg" alt="can't find the path" />
  <img src="/Content/file.jpg" alt="can't find the path" />

Comment: What do you see in your DevTool's Network tab?

Comment: The network tab seems normal, but the console has the following error: "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252862/discussion-between-paine8887-and-dai).